# TypeError: UnionFind is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following user defined data type.

```
class UnionFind{

    constructor(n){
        this.items = n;
    }
    union(p, q){}

    connected(p, q){}

    find(p){}

    count(){}

}
```

I'm using this in the following code.

```
import UnionFind  from "./unionFind.js";
const uf = new UnionFind(10)
```

I'm running this using,

```
node --experimental-modules union-find/client.mjs
```

I get the following error,

```
TypeError: UnionFind is not a constructor
    at file:///Users/mstewart/Dropbox/data-structures-algorithms-princeton/union-find/client.mjs:13:12
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/ModuleJob.js:106:14)
    at <anonymous>
```

If I add export default UnionFind to data type, I get the following error,
export default UnionFind
^^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/Translators.js:53:15)
    at setExecutor (internal/modules/esm/CreateDynamicModule.js:50:23)
```

Comment: may be try `import { UnionFind }  from "./unionFind.js";`

Answer (score 2):

In order for Node module to use `import` or `export` keywords, it should have .mjs extension. `UnionFind is not a constructor` is thrown because `UnionFind` isn't exported from the module.

It should be either `unionFind.mjs`:

```
export default class UnionFind {...}
```

Or `unionFind.js`:

```
module.exports = class UnionFind {...}
```

Which is imported as:

```
import UnionFind from "./unionFind";
```

Notice that interoperation with CommonJS treats `module.export` as default import in ES module.